# Why there is no article before venture capital firm in "Beller’s first high-profile role was at venture capital firm Andreessen Horwitz, .."?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

*Beller’s first high-profile role was at venture capital firm Andreessen Horwitz, where she was a partner on the deal team between 2013 and 2016.*
[Source](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/07/20/facebook-libra-partly-created-by-female-engineer-morgan-beller.html)

Does the same rule apply to the sentence above as to the expressions like *at work*, *in hospital*, and *at school*?
Is *Beller’s first high-profile role was at **a** venture capital firm Andreessen Horwitz, where she was a partner on the deal team between 2013 and 2016.* a correct variant as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of the sentence first as

> Beller’s first high-profile role was at **Andreessen Horwitz**.

Now explain what the name means:

> Beller’s first high-profile role was at **venture capital firm** Andreessen Horwitz.

You would not add an "a" in the first sentence, nor in the second, because the three added words are *adjectival*. Adding "a" would be an article for "Andreessen Horwitz", not for "firm".

But you can rephrase the sentence in two ways, where the punctuation separates the sentence into two noun phrases:

> Beller’s first high-profile role was at **a** venture capital firm, Andreessen Horwitz.
>
> Beller’s first high-profile role was at Andreessen Horwitz, **a** venture capital firm.

Now, the article "a" does indeed belong with "firm".

Comment: 'the' also works.

Comment: @Mitch Just to clarify, is *Beller’s first high-profile role was at **the** venture capital firm Andreessen Horwitz.* correct? I think not. Is *Beller’s first high-profile role was at **the** venture capital firm, Andreessen Horwitz.* correct?  Why and in what context would you rather use ***the*** instead of ***a***?

Comment: IMO it depends on how well known they are. For example, "I talked to **the** actor Michael Douglas" and "I talked to actor Knott Known". Also "I talked to Michael Douglas, **the** actor" and "I talked to Knott Known, **an** actor."

Comment: Remove unnecessaries. 'His role was at _the_ firm Anderessen Horwitz'. 'The' is preferred by far to 'a' or nothing.